# nodejs streams - how to abort reading on error

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I am using 'multiparty' parser to read and process multipart-form-data in my application.  My app middleware reads the uploaded file contents, parses it on-the-fly, and if successful, sends to next middleware.  If not, i have to abort the request and return error.

```
/**
 * Middleware to read n parse uploaded multi-part form data 
 * for campaign creation.
 * After successful parse, sends to next layer.
 *
 **/

var mp = require('multiparty');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("File processor at work...");
  var form = new mp.Form();

  form.on('part', function(part) {
    if (!part.filename) { part.resume();}
    else { 
      part.setEncoding('utf8');
      part.on('readable', function() {
        readFile(req, res,  part); 
      });

      part.on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Am i reached??");
        //return res.status(400).json(e);
        form.emit('error', e);
      })

    }
  });

  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("Error while processing upload.", 3);
    res.status(400).json(err);
  });

  form.on('close', function() {
    console.log("Reading finished. Forwarding to next layer...");
    return next();
  });

  form.parse(req);
}
```

In case of any errors in during parsing (i.e. readFile()), I want to return HTTP error without having to consume the remaining part buffer. I am sure there could be a decent way to do this, but I am not getting it right.

I tried throwing exception from within my readFile(), trying to catch it in form.on('part', ...).  Even though I was able to catch the exception, it didn't abort the flow.  A return() from form.on(part,..) would would return from this evt handler function, but not from the outer function.

As per the nodejs streams documentation, I tried emitting error event from within readFile() and handle the error in part.on('error', ...).  This also gives the same behaviour, and does not end the processing.

What am I missing here?  Is there a proper way to tell the stream that I don't want to process it any further..?